# how to add elements to array using push

Tags: javascript, arrays

Having issues with array data

```
OUT PUTTING LIKE THIS
 [{
     "createdAt": [Object],
     "date": "2021-08-22",
     "description": "Yes"
   }, {
     "title": "greatt"
   }
```

I need it to output like this below

```
    [{
   "createdAt": [Object],
   "date": "2021-08-22",
   "description": "Yes",
   "title": "greatt"
 }
```

```
const myList = [];
myList.push(otherArray, {title: 'Hello'})
```

Comment: Why was the title added to the first array element?

Comment: So you are saying `otherArray` is not an array? That's a confusing name you have there.

Comment: Anyway: `myList.push({...otherArray, title: 'Hello'})`

Comment: Basically what you want is to append the data inside the last object in array ?

Comment: Yes I would like to append the data inside the last object in array

Comment: Your question has actually nothing to do with `push`, nor an array. It is about merging properties from two objects into one.  The array is just a story around it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The result you're getting indicates that `otherArray` is not an array, it's a single object

```
{
    "createdAt": [Object],
    "date": "2021-08-22",
    "description": "Yes"
}
```

So you're pushing two separate objects onto `myList`.

If you want to merge an object into another object, you can use `Object.assign()`.

```
Object.assign(otherArray, {title: 'Hello'});
```

Then you can do

```
myList.push(otherArray);
```

to add that object to the `myList` array.

Answer (score 0):

I think what you want to do is push the extra object values inside the last object of the array ! So here's the solution for that =>

```
let array = [{
    "createdAt": [Object],
    "date": "2021-08-22",
    "description": "Yes"
  }]

  function push(props , array) {
    let lastIndex = array.length - 1;
    array[lastIndex] = Object.assign(props, array[lastIndex]);
  }

  push({
    title: "Title"
  }, array);

  console.log(array)
```

> For more information about `Object.assign` checkout [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/assign)